# Php form duplicates emails

Tags: php, forms, duplicates, html-email

I have a php form that only sometimes duplicates received emails. I have triple checked the code and there is nothing that might make a loop. I have also made a session that prevents identical information from been sent and inserted to the database.. and still I am receiving certain email couple of times..

I have tried to recreate the way that the users might have sent those emails and what may cause it. I found out that what causes this duplication is clicking on the submit button several times. The amount of times I click on the submit button is the amount of duplicated emails I receive.

Does anyone knows why this may happen? And how can I prevent?

Comment: One option: Disable the button after submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are clicking submit button multiple times it is making x request to the server and you are getting x mails. to avoid this you can use following methods.

- Use form token so one form is valid only for one time.
- Disable submit button using javascript after first click to avoid multiple submission.

Comment: Thank you all, I have disabled the button after submission and no more duplicated emails :)

Comment: @orlyidd If my answer helped you. You can select the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do something to the effect of setting a session variable with the timestamp. If the timestamp is less than 30 seconds old die.

```
<?php
session_start();
$sTime = time() - 15;
if($sTime > $_SESISON['submit_timestamp']){
    // process form
} else {
    // some sort of error handling if you want it.
}
?>
```